# Java - add a button in a cell in a Jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, jbutton

I need to add a button to do something, in a cell in a Jtable.
I searched many methods but not work with Netbeans.
I hope your help, as I also contribute to the community.
Thanks in advance.!!

VL

Comment: I am afraid no GUI builder can achieve this functionality. You need to code it by yourself.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706306/how-can-i-add-jbutton-to-last-two-column-cells-of-row/12706653#12706653) example as well

Answer (score 5):

This tutorial should help you out: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm